# Are ssh keys supported by Proxmox for logging into host and guest?

Tags: proxmox

Does Proxmox allow for securing guest logins with keys such as RSA or is it password based only?

Can the host be secured ssh keys too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking to use ssh keys to SSH connection: Yes, of course. Host and Guests are  standard OS with standard SSH package, so you can secure it with ssh keys.

If you're asking to use ssh keys to secure web access to host interface: Nope, it's not possible, but you can use two-factor authorization with google authenticator.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would the console view be affected by ssh keys or would it remain as normal given that it's simulating you sitting next to the machine?

Comment: console view has nothing to do with ssh keys. Its security relies upon https and your web interface authentication